# PHP - Get a variables name? Not its content... Its name?

Tags: php, variables

Please see this example:

```
if (strlen($_SESSION['userDetails']['THISNAME']) == 0)
{
    $_SESSION['userDetails'][''.$THISNAME.'Error'] = "autofocus";
    include "$docRoot/html/forms/reg/user_info.html.php";
    exit();
}
```

How would i use the name of `THISNAME` as I have done to create a new variable that appends Error on the name so in this example the output would be `THISNAMEError`?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do it, you are approaching problem from wrong angle.

Comment: if you are accessing 'THISNAME' key in your conditional then you know what THISNAME is, so you can assign it to a variable `$key = 'THISNAME';` and append error on to it using `$key . `Error`;

Comment: @dm03514 , what he want is this: `$foo = 'bar'; echo magic_function($foo);` outputs `"foo"`.

Comment: @tereško haha magic_function :) yes I like that... Do you have it?

Comment: @BlackberryFan , no, you cannot do it. You will have to explain , what is the problem , which you are trying to solve this way.

Comment: @tereško I would like to rewrite its name to avoid error in hand coding it several times... It is part of a form validation script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$required_fields = array( 'name', 'email', 'password', 'password_verification' );
$errors = array();

foreach ( $required_fields as $field )
{
   if ( !isset($_POST[$field]) )
   {
      $errors[$field] = 'not set';
   }
}

if ( count($errors) > 0 )
{
    // there will be errors in thy forms
}
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: See the answer and comments by Kolink

Comment: @BlackberryFan , you cannot replace the `$required_fields` with just `array_keys($_POST)` because: it may not contain all the required field names(making possible to bypass validation).

Answer (score 2):

You already know "THISNAME" in order to test its length. Why can't you just put it again where you want it?

As a more general thing, though, you can get the list of keys of an array with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array-keys), or loop through them with [`foreach($input as $key=>$value)`](http://php.net/foreach).

Comment: to answer the first part of your question, because that would involve typing it out twice, and there are alot of fields, that seem to be constantly changing... I've found that appending it manually it making the task cumbersome so I thought, being php there must be a simpler way!? As for the second part... I'll have to think about that, thank you for your input though!

Comment: Is there a way to get the names of each field submitted from a form? Like say the form has 4 post fields... a, b, c, d... When you submit the form can you get a output like "a, b, c, d" or is that what `array_keys()` does?

Comment: Yup, just use `array_keys($_POST)`. I frequently use that when getting an array of checkboxes.

Comment: I have given the answer to tereško as he has provided the code (with the addition of your input) that has solved my problem. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Kolink , thats an extremely bad idea, since you can bypass validation by removing the field.

Comment: @tereško At which point validation would fail because the key doesn't exist. The server should have a list of the expected keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
//if(strlen($_SESSION['userDetails'][$THISNAME]) == 0)
//|
//|->if you are checking for $THISNAME,
//   why you then create a new varialbe $THISNAME.'Error' ?

//if(strlen($_SESSION['userDetails']["$THISNAME_Error"]) == 0) {
if( ! isset($_SESSION['userDetails']["$THISNAME_Error"])) {

   $_SESSION['userDetails'][$THISNAME.'_Error'] = "autofocus";
   //or
   $_SESSION['userDetails']["$THISNAME_Error"] = "autofocus";

}
```

Should work

Comment: That would get the variable content then append Error to it? so it could be something like `w0rldartError`? If the variable has the content of `w0rldart` I need `THISNAMEError`.

Comment: check my answer's question, it checks to see if (where `$THISNAME = 'alex'`) `$_SESSION['userDetails']["alex_Error"]`'s length equals to 0.